# how to enable mod rewrite on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to enable mod rewrite on my ec2 server but can't find any of these

"/etc/httpd"
or
"/etc/apache2/httpd"
or 
"/etc/apache2/apache2.conf".

In /etc/apache2 it only has conf-availeble and inside this there are two other files.